# iTunes COM. How to get track's old location with c#?

Tags: c#, itunes-sdk

iTunes has the old location (file path that no longer exist) of track with ! in front of them. I know this because if you right click on track with ! in front of it and select GetInfo (then choose no, don't locate it). Under Summary tab it has a section that shows the song's path (not working). when I try to get the track location using iTumes COM, IITFileOrCDTrack.location return empty string. So, how do I get this "where" value from Getinfo --> Summary tab?

Below is how I currently try to get track location (using C#). My entire iTunes lib has 10songs all of them point to the wrong file location so it doesn't matter which song I chose.

```
iTunesApp itunes = new iTunesApp(); 
IITLibraryPlaylist mainLibrary = itunes.LibraryPlaylist;
IITTrackCollection tracks = mainLibrary.Tracks;
IITFileOrCDTrack currTrack;
currTrack = tracks[5] as IITFileOrCDTrack;
Console.WriteLine(currTrack.location) //output is blank.
```

Answer (score 1):

When the file is found, the "where" value shows `C:\...` but when the file is not found, it shows `file:\\C:\...` within iTunes, and from the code, you can access the location by using the Location property (a bug perhaps, with your code - capitalize the 'L' in 'Location')

From the SDK documentation:

> `HRESULT  Location ([out, retval] BSTR *location)`
>
> Returns the full path to the file represented by this track.
>
> Parameters:
>    location  Returns the full path to the file represented by this track.
>
> Return values:
>
> `S_OK`  The operation was successful.
>    `S_FALSE`  The location could not be retrieved (e.g. no file exists at the expected location).
>    `E_POINTER`  location is `NULL`.
>    `ITUNES_E_OBJECTDELETED`  This track has been deleted.
>    `E_FAIL`  An unexpected error occurred.

I was able to reproduce this (i.e. see the "where" value in itunes, when the file cannot be found, and get null returned from IITFileOrCDTrack.Location. <s>I don't think it is</s>     Unless it is undocumented, it is not possible to return the value if the actual file cannot be found.